# Domain Driven Design, How do I deal with user specific data?

Tags: domain-driven-design

After reading Eric Evans' DDD, I'm trying to apply it to the project I'm managing. There are some user specific query data and I'm not really sure of how to implement this in a DDD way.

For example, if a user queries notices, the application should tell the user wether each post is read or not. Normally in such situations, I would respond with data that looks like following:

```
{
    "notices": [
        {"content": "foo", "is_read": true}, 
        {"content": "bar", "is_read": false}
    ]
}
```

Suppose there is `Notice` entity and `Read` entity that saves wether a `User`  has read it. Also assume that there are so many users reading the notice that retrieving all users for the `is_read` is not a efficient way.

- Since `Read` entity is never queried without  `Notice` entity, I could put it inside a `Notice` aggregate. Then implement query function taking the requesting user as parameter.
- Or I could separate `NoticeRepository` and `ReadRepository`, query notices and then join them in the application layer with reads queried with notice ids.

The first option seems that it is assuming an user querying the notices and corrupting the domain layer with application logics. On the other hand, the second option gives me a feeling that I'm implementing a simple feature in an unnecessarily complicated way. And I cannot really think of other options right now.. What could be the best practice for such a case?

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot really think of other options right now

I can see two possible issues that could be tripping you up.

First, your domain model may be missing an important concept.  How do we know if a Bob read a particular notification or not?  There may be some entity in the domain, perhaps an `Acknowledgement`, that captures Bob, and the document that he read, and perhaps other information interesting to this domain (which version of the document did he read?  When? What channel? when? and so on).

Thus, the view that would produce would look something like the list of active notifications left joined to the acknowledgements from Bob.

The other thing that could cross you up is that trying to do joins "by hand", using repositories to fetch data, is a real drag.  Furthermore, what people have come to realize in the years since the blue book was written, it may not be necessary.  Because queries are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), they don't change the underlying data -- and if the underlying data isn't going to change, we don't *really* need a domain model to protect a business invariant.

Comment: Thanks. Nice point! Might CQRS be what you are telling me in the last paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

This need to go all in a Query Service,

The book of Eric Evans is good basis and it has evolved to more modern patterns now, for instance CQRS in the book of Vaughn Vernon, Implementing Domain Driven Design (IDDD).

Your query service would be responsible of displaying a list of notices, updating a read column for this user in a separate table.

You might have a look at some example of query services (written in java) here:

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/application/forum/ForumQueryService.java

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/application/forum/DiscussionQueryService.java

Comment: Doesn't separating read and write ends up the codebase being duplicated? Also almost every domain repository implements single item retrieval and wouldn't it be simple to just let it display to the client?

Comment: Code being duplicated is not a problem in DDD. Actually its a pro, consider this: you want to update your read model but not your write model, code is already separated, you don't need to check the potential introduction of a regression. Its a win

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have a Read entity. Just Notice and User. In User you would have a list of Notice ids that the user has read (or viceversa, in Notice you would have a list of the User ids who have read the Notice).

Then , to query the info you need to show in the user interface, you have several alternatives, as Vaughn Vernon says in his book Implementing DDD (page 512):

- DTOs
- Mediator
- Domain Payload Object
- State Representations
- Use Case optimal repository queries (closed to CQRS)
- Data Transformers